# Takes no arguments

Tags: python

my program is saying that there is an error and its doesn't take any arguments. Is anyone able to spot the mistake? Its on line 30 and line 12. Thanks

```
class City():
  #define the structure and content of the Student Record
  def _init_(self, name, country, population, language):
    self.name = name  #name will be a string
    self.country = country #country will be a string
    self.population = population #population will be an integer
    self.language = language #language wil be a string
    
def createCitiesArray(num, City):
  citiesArray = []
  for counter in range(num):
    citiesArray.append(City("", "", 0, ""))
  return citiesArray
  
def populateCitiesArray(citiesArray, num):
  for counter in range(num):
    citiesArray[counter].name = str(input("Please enter a city name: "))
    citiesArray[counter].country = str(input("Please enter a country: "))
    citiesArray[counter].population = int(input("Please enter city population: "))
    citiesArray[counter].language = str(input("Please enter main language: "))
  return citiesArray
  
  def displayCitiesArray(citiesArray, num):
    print(citiesArray[counter].name, citiesArray[counter].country)
    for counter in range(num):
      print(citiesArray[counter].name, citiesArray[counter].country, citiesArray[counter].population, citiesArray[counter].language)
      
#Top level program
numOfCities = 3
citiesArray = createCitiesArray(numOfCities, City)
citiesArray = populateCitiesArray(citiesArray, numOfCities)
displayCitiesArray(citiesArray, numOfCities)
```

Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 30, in <module>
  File "python", line 12, in createCitiesArray
TypeError: City() takes no arguments
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The constructor should be named `__init__`, with double underscores before and after, not `_init_`.

Without a suitably named constructor, Python creates a default one for you that takes no arguments.

Answer (score 0):

A constructor in Python is defined as `__init__`, not `_init_` like you currently have (note the double underscores).